# Displaying adjacent td's one on top of the other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have table with four columns. I am trying to get the second column cell to go under the first column cell and the fourth column cell under the third column cell when the viewport goes narrow enough. The solution I here works for IE8+ but it is clumsy. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/hhyen16/6ttc7z03/1/

Code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .inner {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%\9;
    float: left\9;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <caption>TDs to ROWs</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="inner">One</th>
            <th class="inner">Two</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="one" class="inner">cell 1 with some long text</td>
              <td id="two" class="inner">cell 2 with some long text too</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="inner">Three</th>
            <th class="inner">Four</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="three" class="inner">cell 3 with some long text</td>
              <td id="four" class="inner">cell 4 with some long text as well</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" </script>
```

Comment: It works for me as well, Chrome on Mac OS X 10.10. What's the problem?

Comment: This solution requires one to use tables inside a table. I wonder if there is an easy way to get the same result without the inner tables.

Comment: Aah, I didn't even notice that :) I've made it work without the tables in the tables, will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice before you used tables in tables, but it doesn't seem to be necessary. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ttc7z03/2/)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <caption>TDs to TABLE ROWs (table inside table)</caption>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <td id="one" class="inner">cell 1 with some long text</td>
                <td id="two" class="inner">cell 2 with some long text too</td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td id="three" class="inner">cell 3 with some long text</td>
                <td id="four" class="inner">cell 4 with some long text as well</td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    .inner {
        display:table-row;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }
}
#one {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#two {
    background-color: green;
}
#three {
    background-color: gray;
}
#four {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

This seems to work for me the same way as it worked in your old code.
[image]
[image]